# In rust; what types are included in a type's Namespace?

Tags: types, rust, petgraph

I'm studying the source to the [petgraph](https://github.com/petgraph/petgraph) library, and I cannot find out where the type `Graph::NodeId` comes from.

I can see that the function [`astar`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.13/petgraph/algo/fn.astar.html) accepts a type `G` (which can be a [`Graph`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.13/petgraph/graph/struct.Graph.html)). `astar` expects there to be a type `NodeId` in `G`'s namespace.

```rust
pub fn astar<G, F, H, K, IsGoal>(
    graph: G, 
    start: G::NodeId, 
    is_goal: IsGoal, 
    edge_cost: F, 
    estimate_cost: H
) -> Option<(K, Vec<G::NodeId>)> where
    G: IntoEdges + Visitable,
    IsGoal: FnMut(G::NodeId) -> bool,
    G::NodeId: Eq + Hash,
    F: FnMut(G::EdgeRef) -> K,
    H: FnMut(G::NodeId) -> K,
    K: Measure + Copy,
```

I can see that [`Graph`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.13/src/petgraph/graph_impl/mod.rs.html#325-329) is defined as

```rust
pub struct Graph<N, E, Ty = Directed, Ix = DefaultIx> {
    nodes: Vec<Node<N, Ix>>,
    edges: Vec<Edge<E, Ix>>,
    ty: PhantomData<Ty>,
}
```

I don't however, see where the type `NodeId` comes from. The only place I see it defined in the source code is in the trait implementation [`EdgeRef for EdgeReference`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.13/src/petgraph/graph_impl/mod.rs.html#1962)

```rust
impl<'a, Ix, E> EdgeRef for EdgeReference<'a, E, Ix>
    where Ix: IndexType,
{
    type NodeId = NodeIndex<Ix>;
    type EdgeId = EdgeIndex<Ix>;
    type Weight = E;

    fn source(&self) -> Self::NodeId { self.node[0] }
    fn target(&self) -> Self::NodeId { self.node[1] }
    fn weight(&self) -> &E { self.weight }
    fn id(&self) -> Self::EdgeId { self.index }
}
```

But I don't understand how that type would get into scope under `Graph`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`astar` has a bound `G: IntoEdges + Visitable` where `Visitable` is defined as

```rust
pub trait Visitable: GraphBase { … }
```

and `GraphBase` is defined as

```rust
pub trait GraphBase {
    type EdgeId: Copy + PartialEq;
    type NodeId: Copy + PartialEq;
}
```

This is what allows `astar` to use `G::NodeId`. Essentially you have this:

```
struct Graph;

trait GraphBase {
    type Type;
}

trait Visitable: GraphBase {}

impl GraphBase for Graph {
    type Type = u8;
}

impl Visitable for Graph {}

fn foo<G: Visitable>(_: G, _: G::Type) {}

fn main() {
    foo(Graph, 42);
}
```

([Permalink to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=737d67ca87953469d7a28f6106649e89))